# Replacing row-values in matrix by its row index

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, row

I use a r-matrix (for example `[[0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1]]`) representing
 a raster. I'd like to replace every value except 0 with its row index value. Is there something like

```
matrix[matrix==1] <- row_index
```

so that my result would look like `[[0,0,0,1],[0,2,0,2],[3,0,0,0],[0,0,4,4]]`?

I am using R 2.15.1 on a Mac (10.7.5) and RPY2 2.2.6 to start the R-Methods. 
Or is there any other way to get reasonable results for statistical functions like `histogram`, `chi_square` etc.?

Answer (score 5):

For a succinct, expressive solution, I'd be likely to use this:

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), 
            nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)

m[m!=0] <- row(m)[m!=0]
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    2    0    2
# [3,]    3    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    4    4
```

Comment: I was trying with `which(m == 1) %% 4` and was riddled with replacing `0` with `4` (exactly divisible numbers by 4). This is brilliant! Got to remember `row`..

Comment: @Arun -- I feel you. It took me far too long to learn about these three super-useful and related incantations: `m <- diag(3); row(m); col(m); which(m==1, arr.ind=TRUE)`!

Comment: Heh. I didn't even know about `row`. Nice.

Comment: @user2132627, do be sure to click on the checkmark next to Josh's answer to mark his answer as accepted if it is exactly what you were looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully all hell won't break loose for suggesting a for loop, but we'll see:

Here's your matrix

```
mymat <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), 
                nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
mymat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    1    1
```

Here's a for loop that uses basic subsetting to identify the cases you want to replace.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mymat)) {
  mymat[i, ][mymat[i, ] != 0] <- i
}
```

Here's the result.

```
mymat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    2    0    2
# [3,]    3    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing the point of your question, but how about

```
> m <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
+             nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
> m * 1:nrow(m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    2    0    2
[3,]    3    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    4    4
>
```

(ETA: R fills in matrices by column, and the itemwise product operator makes the two matrices involved conformant by replicating them column by column until they fit. The * operator here winds up multiplying each item by the row to which it belongs.)